# OpenGL : drawing line using degenerate triangle

Tags: c++, opengl

In my engine, I want to avoid having line, and separate triangle types. I want to draw the lines using a triangle where 2 verts are identical. But in opengl, this triangle wont be displayed because it has zero area, and therefore can't cover a pixel.

Internally, at the driver level, an opengl line is drawn using a degenerate triangle, and a different rasterization rule is used where it draws at least one pixel per scanline.

D3d had some option where you could set the rasterization to always draw the first pixel per scan line--effectively accomplishing what I want in d3d.

But how can I do this with opengl? I don't see any command that would allow you to change the rasterization rules.

Comment: maybe glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
but if you have to change the state of opengl for lines and polygons anyway, where is the advantage then of not using GL_LINES?

Comment: What is the D3d option you are talking about?

Comment: I don't think I've heard of the D3D flag either... Generally degenerate triangles are rejected at the vertex setup stage in both GL and D3D (eg. even the vertex shader doesn't get executed, let alone the pixel/fragment shader). If you're rendering triangle strips, it would be rather weird to disable degenerate rejection, because for any generic model data, there are usually a large number of degenerates. You'd get... lines all over the place, which I'm not sure why that would be desirable?

Comment: I dont have the exact flag, or the version of directx it showed up in. The d3d flag is set to simulate a wireframe display without using lines. It changes the rasterization to output 1 pixel perscanline, regardless if it covers a pixel or not. This would allow you to draw a degenerate triangle, and it would show up as a line.

Comment: Do you mean D3D11_FILL_WIREFRAME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I did this exact thing by, of the three vertices necessary, using the first two as the start point of the line and then using `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` at the start of the line rendering object and `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)` at the end.

Combine that with the appropriate enabling and disabling of face culling, and you've got yourself a perfectly good line renderer that still uses the triangle set up.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was hoping for but I was able to use it. I have 1 vertexbuffer that needs to hold both lines, and triangles. I add the lines as degenerate triangles, and then at render time, I render the VB once using GL_FILL, and then I render the VB again using GL_LINES.